# InMobi Unity integration error

Tags: unity-game-engine, inmobi

I'm trying to integrate InMobi in a Unity project, but just for testing I am using a clean project with just the InMobi sdk added.
I am running the demo scene included in the unity package.

What I did so far:

- Created a property in the InMobi dashboard
- I enabled test mode on the property
- I added my device to the device test list
- I changed the `_appId` value in `InMobiUI.cs` to the property ID in the InMobi portal.
- I do not have a store URL set for the property, but from what I read it is not mandatory unless you wish to monetize

Today, in my dashboard appeared a warning message that my properties were using an older SDK and that I should upgrade to the latest one. However, there doesn't seem to be any newer Unity plugins than the one I'm already using.

Here is part of the console output I get when running the scene (I marked with `*****` certain sensitive parts of the log):

```
04-23 17:55:05.780: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885): Publisher device Id is ***************************************
04-23 17:55:05.780: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885):  >>>> Start loading new Ad <<<<
04-23 17:55:05.780: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885): Current Ad State: loading
04-23 17:55:05.810: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885): Ad Serving URL: http://i.w.inmobi.com/showad.asm
04-23 17:55:05.810: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885): requestactivity=AdRequest&u-rt=1&tp=p_unity&ts=1398264905820&tz=7200000&c-ap-bssid=162781104347976&d-device-screen-density=3.0&d-device-screen-size=360X640&mk-siteid=2911119936054bb2b3a0ecaccd18448e&u-id-map=ALrF2HWn3cOxH3ebegv8zp8%2FD22bKlUE2QrZss6Mo36RZkbby3mfvcZ0E1JAx0P1b82cPZNiGpAO%0AHvw%2FCM%2BTjSKpyrIpGUJi6WYcSMlxqBZnoiDAByWXgL9JiJYaB7Y0W5KhSJrEGADuRFhT1Fkk5Pis%0AL%2FzKfbhTqhogcdoPO%2Ft5I0PxC46gsyU7eKRVrp8RYhlAZ%2BmklejNNz4aRGiFPkx0xWXjZo%2FP1Vb7%0AZuobc0CzmfTizqo7I1TTSOtFJett%0A&u-id-key=1610128495&u-key-ver=1&aid=8d76bc09-ab63-4b9c-b282-8a03c90d72f3&mk-version=pr-SAND-ETATC-20131017&mk-rel-version=pr-SAND-ETATC-20131017&format=imai&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+4.3%3B+en-us%3B+GT-I9505G+Build%2FJWR66Y.S003%29+AppleWebKit%2F534.30+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F534.30&u-appbid=*******************************&u-appDNM=InMobi+Test&u-appver=1.0&d-localization=en_us&d-netType=wifi&d-orientation=1&mk-ad-slot=15
04-23 17:55:06.421: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885): Http Status Code: 504
04-23 17:55:06.421: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885): Im Id: null
04-23 17:55:06.421: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885): Server Error
04-23 17:55:06.421: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885): Exception retrieving ad 
04-23 17:55:06.421: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885): >>> Got HTTP REQUEST callback. Status: 1
04-23 17:55:06.421: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(31885): INTERNAL_ERROR
04-23 17:55:06.421: I/Unity(31885): onBannerRequestFailedEvent: INTERNAL_ERROR
04-23 17:55:06.421: I/Unity(31885):
```

Another type of error is:

```
04-23 17:57:09.270: D/[InMobi]-[RE]-4.0.2(31885): Viewable:false
04-23 17:57:09.270: D/[InMobi]-[RE]-4.0.2(31885): Injecting JavaScript: window.mraid.broadcastEvent('viewableChange',false);
04-23 17:57:11.523: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): IMAppDatabaseManager->insertEvents-es
04-23 17:57:14.556: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): NetworkManager->handleMessag: msg:{ what=1001 when=-3ms }
04-23 17:57:14.586: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): IMAppDatabaseManager->getEvents
04-23 17:57:14.606: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): IMAppDatabaseManager->es--1
04-23 17:57:14.616: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): PayloadBuilder->getPayloadList:
04-23 17:57:14.646: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): Ping URL: https://e-ltvp.inmobi.com/storm/v1/event
04-23 17:57:15.637: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): Http Status Code: 200
04-23 17:57:15.647: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): IMAppDatabaseManager->deleteEvents
04-23 17:57:15.667: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): Ping Response: {"success":true}
04-23 17:57:18.690: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): NetworkManager->handleMessag: msg:{ what=1001 when=-3ms }
04-23 17:57:18.720: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): IMAppDatabaseManager->getEvents
04-23 17:57:18.740: D/[InMobi]-[Analytics]-4.0.2(31885): PayloadBuilder->getPayloadList:
04-23 17:59:52.290: D/[InMobi]-[AdTracker]-4.0.2(31885): Failed to upload goal in webviewNull App Id OR App Id is not present in server Database
04-23 17:59:52.290: D/[InMobi]-[AdTracker]-4.0.2(31885): Failed to upload goal: download
04-23 17:59:52.290: D/[InMobi]-[AdTracker]-4.0.2(31885): Retrying goalname: download after 900 secs
```

Has anybody got this sort of errors before?

**EDIT 2014-04-25 - fresh error messages and screenshot from the inmobi panel**

The property ID is: 2911119936054bb2b3a0ecaccd18448e

```
04-25 16:41:49.088: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Publisher device Id is *************************
04-25 16:41:49.088: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493):  >>>> Start loading new Ad <<<<
04-25 16:41:49.088: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Current Ad State: loading
04-25 16:41:49.138: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Ad Serving URL: http://i.w.inmobi.com/showad.asm
04-25 16:41:49.138: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): requestactivity=AdRequest&u-rt=1&tp=p_unity&ts=1398433309148&tz=7200000&c-ap-bssid=162781104347976&d-device-screen-density=3.0&d-device-screen-size=360X640&mk-siteid=2911119936054bb2b3a0ecaccd18448e&u-id-map=lCAZ1r6DzEs%2BHyeTcZt4kU%2Bplyov3GOWaGRTiETVrGVlc%2F2IXMif5QxYkKcZ4i8qxjLcIS%2BSPrwu%0AH%2FStYPAFKRvMep75qM5FSm7NpK21K0I2E3PuHHJSyLMynHPdx%2FB75dXYD24%2BKWVLdPhx7dM30p5F%0AaaAplK9o8E70ajaYM5t4ncEflzhUrTVrfAv2qkgNS24m0er438UJ%2BEsntObubgIAtAIpPMuzAXaC%0ANjUCoDFnLr5l0zjZG8ZwaGKjvWap%0A&u-id-key=917209445&u-key-ver=1&aid=85fa54a9-059f-4143-b33c-71013df33348&mk-version=pr-SAND-ETATC-20131017&mk-rel-version=pr-SAND-ETATC-20131017&format=imai&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+4.3%3B+en-us%3B+GT-I9505G+Build%2FJWR66Y.S003%29+AppleWebKit%2F534.30+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F534.30&u-appbid=com.mts.thinkapps.indianelection&u-appDNM=InMobi+Test&u-appver=1.0&d-localization=en_us&d-netType=wifi&d-orientation=1&mk-ad-slot=15
04-25 16:41:49.278: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Http Status Code: 504
04-25 16:41:49.278: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Im Id: null
04-25 16:41:49.278: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Server Error
04-25 16:41:49.278: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Exception retrieving ad 
04-25 16:41:49.278: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): >>> Got HTTP REQUEST callback. Status: 1
04-25 16:41:49.278: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): INTERNAL_ERROR

04-25 16:42:09.297: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Publisher device Id is **********************
04-25 16:42:09.297: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493):  >>>> Start loading new Ad <<<<
04-25 16:42:09.297: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Current Ad State: loading
04-25 16:42:09.317: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Ad Serving URL: http://i.w.inmobi.com/showad.asm
04-25 16:42:09.327: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): requestactivity=AdRequest&u-rt=1&tp=p_unity&ts=1398433329334&tz=7200000&c-ap-bssid=162781104347976&d-device-screen-density=3.0&d-device-screen-size=360X640&mk-siteid=2911119936054bb2b3a0ecaccd18448e&u-id-map=arJTmhI%2BbiWsCbjK6XNDkOTJKSa0bN4Ex4Syuhn0scfhoTeTgrLnmocWxSpMUrg9KgwG75qYQuJx%0ATv%2BKqatge2aiNFVmGONt06xWrqoFt7IPJfj8igGoUuBxoJ4z7HygHvkX8DlCicGUyEp9BX2T0CV1%0ALASxKSvSzJbx2g4CHgiiC%2F68y43SdWIPcnH%2BYjwlRcrhPQjqjZYh6klVMIfsog%2FrgDrvNHK2HjOk%0ARWqk2jw8%2FGRtdjDOpWT8M5DSN7cI%0A&u-id-key=1766756747&u-key-ver=1&aid=85fa54a9-059f-4143-b33c-71013df33348&mk-version=pr-SAND-ETATC-20131017&mk-rel-version=pr-SAND-ETATC-20131017&format=imai&mk-ads=1&h-user-agent=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Linux%3B+U%3B+Android+4.3%3B+en-us%3B+GT-I9505G+Build%2FJWR66Y.S003%29+AppleWebKit%2F534.30+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Version%2F4.0+Mobile+Safari%2F534.30&u-appbid=com.mts.thinkapps.indianelection&u-appDNM=InMobi+Test&u-appver=1.0&d-localization=en_us&d-netType=wifi&d-orientation=1&mk-ad-slot=15
04-25 16:42:09.868: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Http Status Code: 400
04-25 16:42:09.868: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Im Id: null
04-25 16:42:09.868: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Invalid App Id.Please check the app Id in the adrequest is valid and in active state
04-25 16:42:09.878: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Exception retrieving ad 
04-25 16:42:09.878: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): >>> Got HTTP REQUEST callback. Status: 1
04-25 16:42:09.878: D/[InMobi]-[Network]-4.0.2(6493): Your App Id may be invalid or inactive. Please verify the app ID
```

[image: inmobi dashboard for the property]

Answer (score 0):

Sohan from the InMobi team here.

It looks like the site url you have specified in your account is empty. If you want to see test ads, you can turn the [test mode on](https://www.inmobi.com/support/art/23382291/21894911/setting-up-publisher-diagnostics/) and follow the steps listed in the link.

Comment: The test mode is activated. I checked again and I still get that error. I edited my initial post, and included the latest error messages (including the actual ID for the property). It's just a test property.